# Using a matrix vector product to show a specific example

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry

I am suppose to use a matrix vector product to show that if $\theta$ is 180 degrees then $A_\theta v = -v$ for all v in $R^2$

I have no idea what this means and it is really confusing, as far as I can interpret this I have no idea what it means. Is the matrix just 180? Where does 180 go? What is meant by $A_\theta$? As far as I can tell it is a matrix of thetas but I don't know how large or if it really matters at all. I will guess that if all v in $R^2$ part means that my theta matrix is also that size.

So I have a matrix with 180 and 0? I really have no clue what this book is trying to imply and I have even less knowledge on why it is hiding this information from me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $A_\theta$ is supposed to be the matrix representing the linear transformation "rotation an angle $\theta$ around the origin". Check your textbook carefully.

Comment: So if theta shows up do I always assume a rotation matrix? This problems mentions nothing about rotating.

Comment: You have to check your textbook for notation. It varies from book to book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that $A_{\theta}$ is the $2 \times2$ rotation matrix, given by $$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta \\ \end{array} \right)$$
If $\theta=\pi$, it is easy to evaluate $A_{\pi}=-I$

Comment: So how is the conclusion true?

Comment: Well then $A_{\theta}v=-Iv=-v$. Are you familiar with multiplying matrices and vectors?

Comment: But -I is just a fancy way to say a vector that has entry -1,1

Comment: $A_\pi\Bbb v = -I\Bbb v = -\Bbb v$. What do you then mean "a vector that has entry -1,1"? $-I$ is a matrix!

Comment: Oh I thought that forumla meant to subtract sin from cos for the first row and then add sin and cos for the second row. This makes more sense.

Comment: I urge you to review matrix multiplication.